# PSQL TimescaleDB, ERROR: the database system is in recovery mode

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

We have an application pipeline and Postgres-12(TimescaleDB, managed through Patroni)  on a separate server (VM with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).

We are facing an issue with the DB, it suddenly stuck in the recovery mode, and also we can’t access it from the psql client and select queries also hung.

After an hour or late all got back to normal (As my current pipeline terminated) and able to run queries against the DB server.

Master DB error details:

```
2020-11-03 18:35:08.612 IST [9773] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  connection received: host=x.x.x.x port=58780
2020-11-03 18:35:08.612 IST [9773]  FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2020-11-03 18:35:08.596 IST [18276]  LOG:  could not send data to client: Broken pipe
```

Replica server error details:

```
2020-11-03 18:34:55 IST [18316]: [85649-1] user=postgres,db=postgres,app=[unknown],client=x.x.x.x LOG:  duration: 10.228 ms  statement: SELECT * FROM pg_stat_bgwriter;
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2020-11-03 18:35:08 IST [18322]: [2-1] user=,db=,app=,client= FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
2020-11-03 18:35:08 IST [20500]: [1-1] user=,db=,app=,client= FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
        FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
```

Pipeline error details:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 0.0 failed 3 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 29, ip-x-x-x-x.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal, executor 19): org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:514) at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:141) at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192) at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454) at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverWrapper.connect(DriverWrapper.scala:45)
```

Please any advise on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

What version of TimescaleDB are you running?  In particular, there were some issues with 1.7.x if you try to query a read replica; we recommend upgrading to 1.7.4.

(Otherwise, there's not much information about to suggest what might have happened.)

https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/releases/tag/1.7.4

Comment: Thanks for your response! Our TimescaleDB version is 1.7.1 and the Postgres version is 12. Would you please guide how to upgrade without much downtime?

Comment: The default and installed version. **default_version | installed_version 
-----------------+-------------------
 1.7.1           | 1.7.1**